# Add join to SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to add a `join` 'level' to a pre-existing SQL query... unfortunately I keep getting errors with this query. I'm proabably falling somewhere but I cannot understand how to fix it.
The original query is the following:

```
SELECT 
    noleggio.*, 
    nome AS convenzionato
FROM
    anag_convenzionati
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 
    noleggio.*, targa, dc_standard AS dcstandard
FROM
    veicoli_contratti
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 
    noleggio.*,
    nome AS assicurazione_pagante
FROM
    anag_assicurazioni
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT
        fatt_sconto_noleggio,
        fatt_prezzo_noleggio,
        id AS idnoleggio,
        numero,
        serie,
        id_convenzionato,
        stato_noleggio,
        modalita_noleggio,
        conducente,
        locatario,
        locazione_in_proprio,
        id_assicurazione_pagante,
        id_veicolo,
        giorni,
        fatt_giorni_noleggio,
        fatt_prezzo_totale_noleggio,
        data_pagamento_cliente_a_convenzionato,
        ore_manodopera,
        IF(locazione_in_proprio = 1, conducente, locatario) AS cedente
FROM
    noleggio_veicoli
WHERE
    ((data_cancellazione IS NULL) OR (data_cancellazione = ''))
) AS noleggio ON noleggio.id_assicurazione_pagante = anag_assicurazioni.id
) AS noleggio ON noleggio.id_veicolo = veicoli_contratti.id
) AS noleggio ON noleggio.id_convenzionato = anag_convenzionati.id;
```

I need to join the resulting table with `moduli_ocr` table in this way:

```
SELECT 
   noleggio.*
FROM
   (//query//) AS noleggio
        LEFT JOIN
      moduli_ocr ON moduli_ocr.id_noleggio = noleggio.id;
```

Where //query// is the code above.

The error I got (running the query in MySQL Workbench is:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'noleggio.id' in 'on clause'
```

BTW I'm not sure if I have to use `RIGHT` or `LEFT` join but I will check this once the query is properly 'running'.

Best regards.

Comment: You're most likely looking for a `LEFT JOIN`. Could you please show us columns that are in the result of your first query?

Comment: You know, nobody actually uses RIGHT JOIN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you assign idnoleggio alias to the field "id". Try joining on

```
moduli_ocr.id_noleggio = noleggio.idnoleggio;
```